# Show that $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ are independent if $X_t$ is Gaussian

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

If $Y_t=\sum_{i=0}^qa_iX_{t-i}$ where $X_{t-i}$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, how do I show that $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ are independent (for $|h|>q$) using the joint pdf. I know this question has been asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084411/show-that-y-is-a-gaussian-process)) but the answer is not what I'm looking for since independence is not shown, but only that $Y_t$ is Gaussian. I want to show independence between $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ by writing their joint pdf as the product of their marginal pdf's.

Comment: Hi: What you say is only true if $h > q$. Is that condition given ? If not,  then they are not independent.

Comment: @markleeds: Yes, it is given! Sorry I'll edit!

Comment: The way you want to do it seems complex to me. It's easier to just show  that $cov(Y_t, Y_{t+h}) = 0$.Next we know that  marginal distributions of $Y_t,$ and $Y_{t+h}$  are gaussian, Then you can use a theorem that says that, if the covariance of two normally distributed rv's is zero, then they are independent.   Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @markleeds: Thank you very much for this answer! I'll try your method now and get back to you.

Comment: @markleeds - I need some help. Stuck here:

\begin{align}
                \rho_{Y_t}(h)&=\text{Cov}[Y_t,Y_{t+h}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_tY_{t+h}]-\mathbb{E}[Y_t]\mathbb{E}[Y_{t+h}]\\
                &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=0}^{q}\theta_jX_{t-j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^q\theta_iX_{t+h-i}\right)\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{q}\theta_jX_{t-j}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{q}\theta_jX_{t+h-j}\right]\\
                &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=0}^{q}\theta_jX_{t-j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^q\theta_iX_{t+h-i}\right)\right]-\mu^2\sum_{j=0}^q \\
                &=
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure how to treat that product of sums. I can't assume independence since that's what I want to prove.

Comment: Surely the $X_t$ must be independent? If so, I don't see why you need the pdf of anything, as $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ are non-intersecting sums of independent Gaussians.

Comment: @steveo'america - It's nowhere stated that the $X_t$ are independent in the problem. Only that we are to assume that $X$ is a Gaussian process.

Comment: @Parseval if the $X_t$ can have arbitrary dependence on each other, then the statement is clearly false. In the extreme case assume all $X_t = X_0$, then obviously all $Y_t$ are the same.

Comment: @Steveo'america: $h$ is greater than $q$ so, as you stated, the $X$ of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ don't overlap. I'm pretty sure they're independent gaussians because, if they're not, then there's no way to show independence of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$. I basically took the model as an MA(q). Parseval, I'm pretty sure that the independent Gaussian assumption on the $X_t$ is necessary to show what you want to show.

Comment: @Parseval: Assuming independent of Gaussians, then there are no common $X$ in the two summations on the left hand side of what you wrote so you get the same thing on the LHS as the RHS so the whole expression becomes zero. Apologies if this is not the answer you were looking for but you definitely need the independence of the Gaussians along with the $h$ greater than $q$ in order for the statement to hold.

Comment: @markleeds - This is exactly an $\text{MA}(q)$ model. How do I show/motivate that $|h|>q \implies $ the $X$ of $Y_{t}$ and $Y_{t+h}$ don't overlap? And does the fact that they don't overlap mean that I can move the expectation operator inside each of the sums in the product? Why?

Comment: @markleeds - I'm trying to use this formula: https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2215119

But it get's very ugly very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Parseval: Let me put an answer here and hopefully it's clear. I fixed it so that $\mu = 0 $ is not needed but of course, the independent Gaussian assumption is still needed.

(1) $Y_t = \sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} X_{t-i}$

(2) $Y_{t+h} = \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_j X_{t+h-j}$

$ h > q$.

Note that the last (earliest ) term in (2) is $a_{q} X_{t+h-q}$ and first (latest ) term in (1) is $a_{0} X_{t}$. Therefore, since $h > q$, none of the noise terms in $Y_t$ overlap with any of the the noise terms in $Y_{t+h}$.

Now, the usual definition of covariance, gives:

$Cov(Y_{t}, Y_{t+h}) = E(\sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} X_{t-i} \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_{j} X_{t+h-j})  - E(\sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} X_{t-i}) E(\sum_{j=0}^{q} a_j X_{t+h-j}) $

So, for the first term we have the two sums multiplying each other and then an expectation is taken. Then, for the second term, we have two expectations multiplying each other.

FIRST SIMPLIFY THE SECOND TERM

Taking the expectations of the terms, we get  $\sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} \mu \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_j \mu =  \mu^2 \sum_{i=0}^{q} a_{i} \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_j$.

Simplifying this, results in:

$ \mu^2 \sum_{i=0}^{q} \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_i a_j $

NOW SIMPLIFY THE FIRST TERM:

$ E(\sum_{i=0}^{q} a_i X_{t-i}  \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_j X_{t+h-j}) = $

$( \sum_{i=0}^{q} \sum_{j=0}^{q} a_{i} a_j ) E(X_{t-i} X_{t+h-j})$

But we showed earlier than that none of the terms in the very last expectation overlap, and, since they are independent Gaussians, we can re-write the last expression as $ E(X_{t-i} X_{(t+h-j)}) = E(X_{t-i}) E(X_{(t+h-j)}) = \mu^2$.

So, we showed that the first term equals the same thing as the second term which means that $Cov(Y_{t}, Y_{t+h}) = 0 $.

Note though that I needed the assumption that the X_{t} are independent Gaussian RV's but this is the usual assumption in the MA(q) model.

Comment: Hello Mark! Well the problem clearly specifies that $X\sim\text{WN}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ which is weird :S. I have a question regarding why you set $a_{j+h}$ for $Y_{t+h}$? Should't you only add index $h$ to the random variables? $a_i$ are constants.

Comment: Hi Parseval: I'm pretty sure that $\mu$ needs to be zero. I have to leave and will be gone for most of the day but I'll fix the notation when I get back tonight. As far as notation, I messed up and I should have written $(t +h - j) $ rather than $t-(j+h)$. Hopefully someone else can add to discussion and give insight on whether we need $\mu = 0$. I tried to work it out without that assumption and wasn't successful. Talk to you later.

Comment: The mean of the $X_t$ is irrelevant, as if $\mu \ne 0$, subtract it out and adjust the mean values of the $Y_t$. Independence should not be orthogonal to the mean value.

Comment: You are assuming the $X_t$ are independent Gaussians. No further analysis should be required at that point, as $Y_t, Y_{t+h}$ are sums of non-intersecting independent Gaussians.

Comment: @steveo'america: I fixed it so that it  just needed the non-intersecting independent Gaussians assumption and not the $\mu = 0$ assumption.  Thanks for your help. Parseval: I fixed the notation also so hopefully it's clearer than it was previously. Thanks for pointing out the notation problems.

Comment: Well, if the $X_t$ don't overlap for $|h|>q$ then this implies that they are independent for $|h|>q$ thus it's ok to assume independence in this case. I think this is the reason why they specified $|h|>q$.

Comment: Parseval: That's not necessarily true. Just because two $X_t$ and $X_{t+h}$ don't overlap, they can still be dependent. ( Just consider an autocorrelation function that doesn't die out at $h$ ). . This is why one needs the independence assumption for the proof to work out. One also needs the $h > q$ assumption because, if $h <= q$, then some common $X_t$ are in both $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ which means that $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ would  be dependent not due to statistical dependence but due to them containing some common $X_{t}$. This is why one needs the independence aand the $h > q$ assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to assume the $X_t$ are independent, then write $\vec{X}$ as the vector of $X_{t-q},\ldots,X_t,X_{t+h-q},\ldots,X_{t+h}$. Then $\vec{X} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu \vec{1},\Sigma\right)$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. Then the vector of the two $Y$ values is $A \vec{X}$ for some block matrix that has one row of $q+1$ of the $a_i$, then $q+1$ zeros, then $q+1$ zeros and then the $a_i$ in the second row. Simple to confirm that $A\Sigma A^{\top}$ is diagonal.

Comment: We need not require all $X_t$ be independent, of course, only that the first $q+1$ elements of $\vec{X}$ be independent of the second $q+1$ elements, which would make $\Sigma$ block diagonal (2x2).

Comment: He did add later than it was an MA(q) so all the $X_{t}$ are independent. I like your proof with the block diagonal argument. It's more "visual" than ugly algebra.

Comment: Parseval: Even with the  independence assumption, you still need the $h > q$ assumption, Otherwise, if $h$ was not necessarily greater than $q$ as steveoamerica pointed, you would have some terms that were the same in the two $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$ which makes $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+h}$  "dependent" because they contain some of  the same terms. But, "dependent" is maybe a misleading term in that case. It's more like "common term" dependent.